# React DOM - Form with multiple <select>, remove option from another <select> after choose one option

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, drop-down-menu, state

I have a form with 4  inputs consuming data from the same state. What I want is, after a selection, the choose option will be removed from the another 3 selects.

I've tried many things, is difficult to list here, but in a nutshell: I create another list of selected options, filter the players array with this another list, map this and etc..

The problem with this approach is: i don't want to remove the selected item from the input where it was selected. So, i try to create copy of the same original list to each input. But, i think this way too much 'work around'.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MatchPlayerSelect extends Component {
   state = {
      selectedPlayers: [],
      players: [
         {
            name:"edmiel",
            matches:0,
            wins:0
         },
         {
            name:"willian",
            matches:0,
            wins:0
         },
         {
            name:"gustavo",
            matches:0,
            wins:0
         },
         {
            name:"gabriel",
            matches:0,
            wins:0
         }
     ]
   }

   render() {
      const {players, selectedPlayers} = this.state;

      return (
         <div className="match-player">
            <select onChange={this.setPlayer.bind(this)}>
               <option defaultValue value="">-</option>
               {
                  // i need to filter list here
                  // but this code only list the items on state
                  players.map((player, index) => {
                     return(
                        <option key={index} value={player}>
                           {player.name}
                        </option>
                     )
                  })
               }
            </select>
         </div>
      );
   }

   setPlayer(sender) {      
      this.setState({ selectedPlayer: [...this.state.selectedPlayers, 
      sender.target.value] });
   }

}
```

I need to all select component render each state player (already doing this in the code above). But, when selected, i need to remove this selected option from the another inputs without remove from the focus select input. If exist a better solution to do this in React, please let me know how.

I need to do this using react jsx tools or vanilla js. No jquery!
That's all.

Comment: I don't understand what to want to do, on selecting a player what should happen? The option should disappear? Please edit your question and show the desired behavior.

Comment: I described the problem above well, I don't know how I can better explain :(

Comment: You can just filter the players by the selectedPlayers, read about #filter and #includes

Comment: I want to be clear although I commented it a couple of times, you need to make a producible example, show us your form with multiple selectors, show us some effort you've done to solve the problem and briefly explain the desired input and output of your examples and whats not working, thats how SO works, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So for first, you should remove `this.selectPlayer.bind(this)` from the render method, this is not good for React, for more please follow this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36/).
In the current situation, you need to add one extra array and totally it should look like:
1. `players` - there you should keep all players(this one serves for filtering only).
2. `filteredPlayers` - there you should keep the filtered players(this one servers for render the options list).
3. `selectedPlayersIds`- sure, that the array where you collect all selected player's ids.
Every time when selecting a player, you'll take `players` array and removing all selected players + new selected player and assign to `filteredPlayers` array.
Code Snippet(selectPlayer function)

```
const selectedPlayersIds= [...this.state.selectedPlayersIds, newPlayer.id];
this.setState({
  filteredPlayers: this.state.players.filter(player => this.selectedPlayerIds.indexOf(player.id) !== -1),
  selectedPlayersIds
})
```

Comment: This will work with multiple <select> consuming this same 'filteredPlayers'?

Answer (score 0):

Use [#Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [#Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), moreover, you need to apply a few fixes to your code to make it work:

- At `setPlayer` change the key to `selectedPlayers` instead `selectedPlayer`
- On mapping the `players` array to `option` the `value` property needs to be `player.name` and not `player`

```
players
  .filter(player => !selectedPlayers.includes(player.name))
  .map((player, index) => (
    <option key={index} value={player.name}>
      {player.name}
    </option>
  ));
```

#### Full example:

```
class MatchPlayerSelect extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedPlayers: [],
    players: [
      {
        name: 'edmiel',
        matches: 0,
        wins: 0
      },
      {
        name: 'willian',
        matches: 0,
        wins: 0
      },
      {
        name: 'gustavo',
        matches: 0,
        wins: 0
      },
      {
        name: 'gabriel',
        matches: 0,
        wins: 0
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const { players, selectedPlayers } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="match-player">
        <select onChange={this.setPlayer}>
          <option defaultValue value="">
            -
          </option>
          {players
            .filter(player => !selectedPlayers.includes(player.name))
            .map((player, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={player.name}>
                {player.name}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(selectedPlayers)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  setPlayer = sender => {
    const { selectedPlayers } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      selectedPlayers: [...selectedPlayers, sender.target.value]
    });
  };
}
ReactDOM.render(<MatchPlayerSelect />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit Q]

Comment: Nice, I've done this. The problem with this approach is that selected player is deleted from the current focus <select> element. My idea is maintain all possible options at <select> context.

At the moment that I select a player on <select1>(with 4 options) all the others <select> need to have only 3 options, but <select1> still have 4 options, you get it?

Comment: No, I didn't get it, do you mean you have multiple select? You didn't mention it in the question. As adviced beforehand, make a desired behavior example.

Comment: Yeah, I've a "form with multiple select" is in the title of the question. i'll edit the question to make this more specific. I have 4 <select> form listing options from the same state, like you do on your answer. But, I need a interact between these 4 <select> options.

Comment: I don't see any producible example in your question and either any form, you just changed the title. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)